# Drop-Down Menu Bar Display Behind Google Map

Tags: javascript

Please visit www.flex-bim.com

I am developing this website and have installed Google Map API to display LIVE Map on my index page. the LIVE Map is ok but the CSS Drop-Down Menu Bar now display behind the Google Map.

Below is the Google Map API property i applied but did not work. Please, i need a code line to fix this mess. thanks you.

mapTypeControlStyle: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU

Comment: I was going to explore using `z-index` but the site is hurting my eyes.

Comment: what the... that animation is even worse than 90s homepages with animated gifs of pink unicorns on neon-green background colors

Comment: The 90s called to tell you that even in the 90s, this was a horrible website.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Delete that website.
Step 2: Read about basic web design and structure.
Step 3: Return to this website once you've learned a thing or two.